# Method with Optional return type returns null value

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, option-type

I have the two methods as defined below.

```
    public Optional<String> getSomething(final String input) throws ContainerException {
        try{
            return Optional.of(globals.getParam(GlobalsClass.Keys.SOME_ID).strict().stringValue());
        } catch(ContainerException e) {
            log.error(e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

```
    @Test
    public void test_get_something() {
        try {
            final Optional<String> something = client.getSomething("24430881");
            if(something.isPresent()) {
                System.out.println(something.get());
            }
        } catch (ContainerException e) {
            Assert.fail("Should not have thrown any exception");
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I am getting a NullPointerException for `something.isPresent()` as `something` is `null`. Shouldn't it be Optional.empty()? Can't get why a `null` value is returned by `getSomething()`.

Comment: read the api doc? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#of-T-  this throws NPE if value passed in is null. use ofNullable instead.

Comment: still the same error @NathanHughes

Comment: The code you have posted can’t return neither, `null` nor an empty optional. So the code you have posted doesn’t match the code that produced that exception. By the way, for a unit test, there is no need to catch exceptions with an `Assert.fail(…)` handler. Just add a `throws` declaration to the method and let the exception go to the caller. The test will be marked as failed anyway if an exception occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Since you invoke `getSomething` from the unit test I'd guess that `client` is a Mock and you forgot to explicitly mock it's method like following:

```
// with Mockito
when(client.getSomething(any(String.class)))
    .thenReturn(Optional.of("someResponse"));
```

When you don't do it then Mock's method returns `null` (not `Optional.empty()`!) by default

Comment: why should I mock the method that I am testing @Nikolai Shevchenko. I should have been mocking only the dependent code inside the method to be tested.

Comment: @VipulLohani just an assumption :) it's very common error